# Merging a array of json objects into single objects using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of json objects like these which looks like this

```
[{
    "Name": "Nikhil",
    "Surname": "Agrawal"
}, {
    "profession": "java developer",
    "experience": "2 years"
}, {
    "company": "xyz",
    "city": "hyderabad"
}]
```

Now what I am trying to do is combining the whole array into single json object

```
{
    "Name": "Nikhil",
    "Surname": "Agrawal"
    "profession": "java developer",
    "experience": "2 years"
    "company": "xyz",
    "city": "hyderabad"
}
```

I am trying with this `jQuery.merge(firstObject, secondObject)`but it takes only two arguments So again I need to apply loop and swapping the objects and so a complex logic. Is there any other way to merge this??

Comment: @GeorgeStocker there could be other duplicates but the one marked here is about creating a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done in a single call so try

```
var obj = {};
$.each(arr, function (i, o) {
    $.extend(obj, o)
})
console.log(obj)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dzgyE/)

Comment: Sir thank you. you helped me second time. +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript**

```
var json = [{
    "Name": "Nikhil",
    "Surname": "Agrawal"
}, {
    "profession": "java developer",
    "experience": "2 years"
}, {
    "company": "xyz",
    "city": "hyderabad"
}];

var newObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    for(x in json[i]){
        console.log(x);
        newObj[x] = json[i][x];       
    }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wVGah/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `.extend` function like this:

```
var json = [{"Name": "Nikhil","Surname": "Agrawal"},{"profession": "java developer","experience":"2 years"},{"company": "xyz","city":"hyderabad"}];

var json2 = json[0];

for(var i = 1; i<json.length; i++){
    $.extend(json2,json[i]);
}
```

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Bt7/)